# Fetching tweets from twitter using retun statament from a dict in list in python

Tags: python, twitter

So the below function is working for print statement but not for return stament How can i get the count no of tweets using return statement

```
>>>import requests
>>>from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
>>>import urllib

# Credentials to fetch
>>>consumer_key = '********'  
>>>consumer_secret = '******************'  
>>>url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json'



>>>def get_keyword_tweets(keyword, Count):  
   param = urllib.urlencode({'q': keyword, 'lang': 'en', 'result_type':
                          'recent', 'count': Count})  
   url2 = url.endswith('?') and (url+param) or (url + '?' + param)  
   auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_secret)  
   r = requests.get(url2, auth=auth)  
   tweets = r.json()  
   keywordtweets = tweets['statuses']  
   dict1 = keywordtweets[0:Count]  
   #data = dict1['id_str'],dict1['text']  
   for tweet in dict1:  
      data = tweet['id_str'],tweet['text']  
      print data  
   return data
```

The output i am getting when i am using the above function is

```
>>>In [1]: from http_twitter import get_keyword_tweets  

>>>In [2]: get_keyword_tweets("CWC15",Count=4)  
(u'578172948231495680', u'RT @ICC: Fascinating stat from Pool Stages with the breakdown of wickets in the tournament, just wait for #AUSvPAK!! \n#cwc15 http://t.co/Jw\u2026')  

(u'578172941977808896', u'RT @Surbhivb: Venkat: on the UAE cricket team, led by Khurram Khan, an airline purser. Only fully amateur team in the #CWC15. http://t.co/c\u2026')  

(u'578172938467176448', u'RT @iTweety_19: "I am ready to go to the World Cup if the selectors pick me as the replacement for Mohammad Irfan" says @REALsaeedajmal \n#c\u2026')  

(u'578172935115960320', u'Thank you @KumarSanga2 &amp; @MahelaJay for all the epic partnerships! #ThankYouSanga #ThankYouMahela #SAvSL #CWC15 http://t.co/li0QgPniI0"')  
(((((The above output is for print data"(i got 4 tweets as i mentioned)")))))  

Out[2]:   
(u'578172935115960320',
 u'Thank you @KumarSanga2 &amp; @MahelaJay for all the epic partnerships! #ThankYouSanga #ThankYouMahela #SAvSL #CWC15 http://t.co/li0QgPniI0"')
```

(((((The above output is for 'return data'(I got only one tweet but i need four))))))
so how can i return the count no of tweets Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you return `dict1` (which is a list, not a dict), rather than `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning just 1 data at the end. You need to return a `list` or the whole `dict` as pointed out in a comment above.

replace:-

```
for tweet in dict1:  
  data = tweet['id_str'],tweet['text']  
  print data  
return data
```

By:-

```
data_list = []
for tweet in dict1:  
  data = tweet['id_str'] + tweet['text']
  data_list.append(data)
  print data  
return data_list
```